# how should I design changing GUIs?

Tags: java, swing

I need a panel with text fields a,b,c for project AA.
I need another panel with text fields a,b,d,e,f for project BB.
In future I will definitely need another panel with text fields a,b,d,y,z for project CC.
Again in future I may need another panel with... etc.

a and b text fields are common for all projects and d is common for BB and CC. 
Layout of common fields may differ. Panels include methods such as createComponents, guiLayout, refresh, save, getGUIErrors...

Now, How should I design my panels? What about inheritance? Is defining a common panel including fields a,b and extending it for projects correct? Is it possible to use composition, decorator pattern ?

Of course question can be extended to models and controllers.

thank you .

Comment: You should check out Card Layout.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I use cardlayout. but my problem is about panels that I add to container with cardLayout.

Comment: In short ın GUI design is it a good practice to use inheritance or should I duplicate the GUI codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, How should I design my panels? What about inheritance? Is defining a common panel including fields a,b and extending it for projects correct? Is it possible to use composition, decorator pattern ?

While code reuse is generally good, it seems to me you are overcomplicating things here. Why bother with all that work if it is simply to re-use two textfields on a panel. We are talking about two lines of code.

If all your panels look pretty similar, use a decent layout builder and reuse that one (see for example the builder available for the FormLayout of JGoodies).

Next to that, the typical UI layer is pretty thin. Re-use your business side (the models behind the UI) if needed/possible, but do not bother with the UI. In my experience, this lead to much cleaner code.
I have seen too many UIs/panels where the constructor takes a lot of boolean flags to include/exclude certain fields, a bunch of protected methods to provide access to all components (e.g. to disable a certain field on certain conditions), ... in short, a lot of code because in the end no two UIs are the same and you always have to customize.

Comment: I said two text fields for si

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually I have 10-15 fields in common. Maybe it is my fault to say there are two common fields but I just wanted to simplfiy the question. Duplicating the UI codes is one of my candidate solutions, it is the fastest and cheapest way. But what will happen if I change label of the common field in one panel and forget to update the other one?